# Need help getting graphics of a plot and point

Tags: plotting

I had reworded this question to help beginners understand the difference between the graphic and the simple plot function.

I want a graph showing 2 functions and a point in the graph. I am trying to use the Plot command but the point is not shown in the output

```
Plot[{(x/Pi)^2 - 2, 3 Sin[x - Pi], Point[2, 2]}, {x, -2, 3 Pi}]
```

The two functions are shown in the plot graph but not the point.

Comment: 1) you have two consecutive commas; 2) `Point` takes a list, not a number of coordinates; 3) `Plot` is for continuous functions, and `Point` is not a function at all - put the point in `Epilog`:  `Plot[{(x/Pi)^2 - 2, 3 Sin[x - Pi]}, {x, -2, 3 Pi}, 
 Epilog -> Point[{2, 2}]]`.

Comment: `Point` is a graphics primitive; not function of $x$.

Comment: Why would you expect this syntax to work?  Have you seen such a usage of `Point` anywhere in the documentation?

Comment: An alternative to `Epilog` and `Prolog`, is `Show[Plot[..], Graphics[{.., Point[{2,2}],..}]]`, where `..` indicate you can fill in with code as needed.

Comment: It is very rude for you to close my topic.  This question is intended for beginners with entree level skills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your input, a variant would look like:

```
Plot[{(x/Pi)^2 - 2, 3 Sin[x - Pi]}, {x, -2, 3 Pi}, 
Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{2, 2}]}]
```

[image]

And to find other Points of Interest:

```
sols = NSolve[(x/Pi)^2 - 2 == 3 Sin[x - Pi] && 0 < x < 7, x]
```

> `{{x->0.707284},{x->2.70957},{x->5.79618}}`

```
IntrsctnPoints = {x, f1[x]} /. sols
```

> `{{0.707284,-1.94931},{2.70957,-1.25612},{5.79618,1.40395}}`

```
Plot[{(x/Pi)^2 - 2, 3 Sin[x - Pi]}, {x, -2, 3 Pi}, 
Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point@IntrsctnPoints}]
```

[image]